# Función para sumar tasas en PHP

Tags: php, php7

Necesito hacer una función que sume tasas de interés de distintos meses.
Tengo todos los meses de varios años con números distintos

Por ejemplo:

- $enero_2015 = 2.25;
- $febrero_2015 = 2.34;
- $marzo_2021 = 3.25;

Tengo el mes y año de inicio, también el mes y año de finalización `$mes_inicio = 05/18;` y `$mes_finalizacion = 09/21;`

Necesito que sume cada tasa de interés de cada mes, empezando en el mes y año de inicio y terminando en el mes y año de finalización.

```
for($i = 0 ; $i < $cantidad_total_meses; $i++){

    switch($mes_inicio){
        case 01:
           
            $tasa_acumulada = $tasa_acumulada + $enero_15;
            break;
        case 02:
            $tasa_acumulada = $tasa_acumulada + $febrero_15;
            break;
            case 03:
                $tasa_acumulada = $tasa_acumulada + $marzo_15;
                break;
    }
}
```

Con ello (terminando esa función) puedo obtener la tasa del mes de inicio y puedo pasar a otro `for` y hacer lo mismo con el mes de finalización, el problema que tengo es que no sé cómo ir sumando los meses entre medio.

Comment: Como calculas las tasas de interés? Ejemplo: tengo un monto de $450 a un interés mensual del 10%. Si fue por 3 meses, debería ser: valor total por interés total; $1350 * 1,3 (equivale al 30% acumulado por mes) y lo sumas, lo que da como resultado $1755. Esta bien como lo interpreto?

Comment: No, siguiendo tu ejemplo, tenes $450 a un interes mensual del 10$ si fue por 3 meses seria $450 + 30% = $585. Saludos

Comment: Segun el codigo mostrado  no  hara la función de acumular porque las variables son distintas  $enero_2015 = 2.25; y en el case se llama $enero_15, si lo obtienes de BD con un solo recorrido se podrá obtener todo asumiendo que en la estructura cada mes tiene un ID independiente del año, segun le entiendo al codigo proporcinado.

Comment: @SebastianMostazo entiendo, entonces por que no guardas los datos en un array y los sumas; `$suma = array("enero_2015" => 2.25, "febrero_2015" => 2.34, "$marzo_2021" => 3.25); echo "Total = " . array_sum($suma);` resultado: `Total = 7.84`

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo resolverlo así, para tipos de interés **anuales** y liquidaciones **mensuales**.

```
<?php

$interes=[
    strtotime('2015-01-01')=>2.25,
    strtotime('2015-02-01')=>2.34,
    strtotime('2021-03-01')=>3.25,
];

$ini=strtotime('2018-05-01');
$fin=strtotime('2021-09-01');

$capital=450;
$tipo=2.25;
$mes=date('m',$ini);
for($i=$ini;$i<=$fin;$i+=60*60*24){
    if($mes!=date('m',$i)){
        $mes=date('m',$i);
        foreach($interes as $t=>$int) if($i>=$t) $tipo=$int;
        $capital+=$tipo/100/12*$capital;
        echo '<div>'
            .date('d/m/Y',$i)
            .' - '.$tipo
            .'% - '.number_format($capital,2,',','.')
            .'</div>';
    }
}
```

Con lo que obtendrías esta tabla:

```
01/06/2018 - 2.34% - 450,88
01/07/2018 - 2.34% - 451,76
01/08/2018 - 2.34% - 452,64
01/09/2018 - 2.34% - 453,52
01/10/2018 - 2.34% - 454,40
01/11/2018 - 2.34% - 455,29
01/12/2018 - 2.34% - 456,18
01/01/2019 - 2.34% - 457,07
01/02/2019 - 2.34% - 457,96
01/03/2019 - 2.34% - 458,85
01/04/2019 - 2.34% - 459,75
01/05/2019 - 2.34% - 460,64
01/06/2019 - 2.34% - 461,54
01/07/2019 - 2.34% - 462,44
01/08/2019 - 2.34% - 463,34
01/09/2019 - 2.34% - 464,25
01/10/2019 - 2.34% - 465,15
01/11/2019 - 2.34% - 466,06
01/12/2019 - 2.34% - 466,97
01/01/2020 - 2.34% - 467,88
01/02/2020 - 2.34% - 468,79
01/03/2020 - 2.34% - 469,71
01/04/2020 - 2.34% - 470,62
01/05/2020 - 2.34% - 471,54
01/06/2020 - 2.34% - 472,46
01/07/2020 - 2.34% - 473,38
01/08/2020 - 2.34% - 474,30
01/09/2020 - 2.34% - 475,23
01/10/2020 - 2.34% - 476,15
01/11/2020 - 2.34% - 477,08
01/12/2020 - 2.34% - 478,01
01/01/2021 - 2.34% - 478,95
01/02/2021 - 2.34% - 479,88
01/03/2021 - 3.25% - 481,18
01/04/2021 - 3.25% - 482,48
01/05/2021 - 3.25% - 483,79
01/06/2021 - 3.25% - 485,10
01/07/2021 - 3.25% - 486,41
01/08/2021 - 3.25% - 487,73
01/09/2021 - 3.25% - 489,05
```

Espero que cuadre con tus cálculos.